# How to rendering different markup for each record from mysql select?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a set of items to select from mysql. And then I want to display these items on my page with different 'markup`.

This is how my HTML look like for each item.

```
<ul class='unstyled main-facilities row'>
    <li class='info-facility-item '>
        <span class='fa-stack'>
            <i class='fa fa-square fa-stack-2x'></i>
            <i class='fa fa fa-cutlery fa-stack-1x fa-inverse'></i>
        </span> Item-01
    </li>
    <li class='info-facility-item '>
        <span class='fa-stack'>
            <i class='fa fa-square fa-stack-2x'></i>
            <i class='fa fa fa-rss fa-stack-1x fa-inverse'></i>
        </span> Item-02
    </li>
    <li class='info-facility-item '>
        <span class='fa-stack'>
            <i class='fa fa-square fa-stack-2x'></i>
            <i class='fa fa-refresh fa-stack-1x fa-inverse'></i>
        </span> Item-03
    </li>
    ...
    ...
    ...

</ul>
```

If I have same markup for each item, then I can do it like this:

```
// Fetch all the records:
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    $result  = "<li class='info-facility-item '>\n";
    $result .= "    <span class='fa-stack'>\n";
    $result .= "        <i class='fa fa-square fa-stack-2x'></i>\n";
    $result .= "        <i class='fa fa fa-rss fa-stack-1x fa-inverse'></i>\n";
    $result .= "    </span>{$item}\n";
    $result .= "</li>\n";
    $items[] = $result;     
    }           
}
```

But I am not sure how to modify my `while` loop to render different markup for each item.

Can anybody tell me is there a way to do this in PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to style each `li` differently or you want different mark up altogether? I think you should be able to give each `li` an ID then style them in css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the values you need to set to each position you could solve this like this:
**Look at the array `$val`**

```
$val= array("value0", "value1", "value2");
$i = 0;
// Fetch all the records:
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    $result  = "<li class='info-facility-item '>\n";
    $result .= "    <span class='fa-stack'>\n";
    $result .= "        <i class='fa fa-square fa-stack-2x'></i>\n";
    $result .= "        <i class='fa fa {$val[$i]} fa-stack-1x fa-inverse'></i>\n";
    $result .= "    </span>{$item}\n";
    $result .= "</li>\n";
    $items[] = $result;     
    $i++;           
}
```

Comment: Your solution is ok. but I need to change second `<i>` under `span` tag for each item. Thats the problem

Comment: @user3733831 well the change would be almost the same, you can use the `$i` to add a `class` or an `id` to the second `<i>`. Ex `$result .= "        <i id="{i$id}" class='fa fa fa-rss fa-stack-1x fa-inverse'></i>\n";`

Comment: You are correct. But I need to use pre defined class names for `<i>` tag. Check my HTML in question.

Answer (score 1):

code below generates 4 different css classes that are added to the sequential LI. If you want - you can add more similar classes elsewhere. The name of the new classes will be `new_class0`, `new_class1`, ...
Is  that what you need?

```
<?php
//Fetch all the records:
$xi = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ( $xi > 3 ) {
        $xi = 0;
    }
    $result  = "<li class=\"info-facility-item new_class{$xi}\">\n";
    $result .= "    <span class='fa-stack'>\n";
    $result .= "        <i class='fa fa-square fa-stack-2x'></i>\n";
    if ( $xi == 0 ) {
        $result .= "        <i class='fa fa fa-rss fa-stack-1x fa-inverse'></i>\n";
    else if ( $xi == 1 ) {
        $result .= "        <i class='fa fa fa-cutlery fa-stack-1x fa-inverse'></i>\n";
    }
    $result .= "    </span>{$item}\n";
    $result .= "</li>\n";
    $items[] = $result;      
    $xi += 1;                    
}
```